# Is using "I don't know that" instead of "I don't know if" grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, conjunctions

When asked whether he recognized equal rights of atheists, George H. W. Bush said<sup>1</sup>:

> No, I don't know that atheists should be considered as citizens, nor
>   should they be considered patriots. This is one nation under God.

I would understand if he had used another verb:

> No, I don't think/believe that atheists should be considered...

I would also understand if he had chosen another conjunction:

> No, I don't know if atheists should be considered...

Is the original quoted sentence grammatically correct? Is it common to use **know** in the sense of **think**? Or is this some dialect-specific meaning? Could you please give some more examples of this usage of **know**?

<sup>1 [Wikipedia source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrimination_against_atheists#United_States)</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string *I don't know that* is grammatical and [common](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14318364) and is used to express doubt. The use of subordinators *if* or *whether* after *know* would suggest a less firm position: he doesn't know or he's not so certain.

- *I don't know that there are bargains yet, but there certainly are opportunities.*
- *I don't know that the President has said that he fully supports the conference of the states*
- *I don't know that his chances are any better now than they were then*

Comment: Could I say: "I don't know that he is a competent professional."?

Comment: Yes, especially if the stress was on *competent*. It would commonly be followed by something like, "but he has passed the licensing tests."

Comment: Could I ask you to update your answer with a couple of typical sentences with this meaning of know, please?

Comment: I've added a few, but if you click on the link, and then click on the result, it will give you thousands of relevant examples (mixed in with some non-relevant ones.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is grammatically correct, albeit informal. It is an idiomatic use of the verb [know](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/know?q=know), meaning *I have doubts about somebody's ability to do something.* The entry in the Oxford Dictionaries Online reads as follows:

**not know that** (informal) used to express one’s doubts about one’s ability to do something: *I don’t know that I can sum up my meaning on paper.*

Comment: Do you have any reference or basis for your claim that this usage is "informal" and/or "idiomatic"?  To the contrary, the first meaning of *[know](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/know)* in wiktionary is neither informal nor idiomatic: "To be certain or sure about. (eg) I know that I’m right and you’re wrong", from which "don't know" means uncertain, unsure.

Comment: @jwpat7: If you follow the link of my answer to Oxford Dictionary, you will see the reference for my claim. Just scroll down to the phrases listed until you reach **not know that**
(informal) used to express one’s doubts about one’s ability to do something:
 
*I don’t know that I can sum up my meaning on paper*

Comment: Will you add that into your answer?

Comment: @jwpat7: I just edited my answer per your instructions.

Comment: I wonder why it's specifically doubts about *ability*? I would have thought that "I don't know that he can run that fast" and "I don't know that he wants to run that fast" were equally plausible. Having said that, it's not a turn of phrase I would ever use myself.